# using json with jquery for jtables?

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am using jtables (http://www.jtable.org), but one of the options to create a combobox (dropdown menu) is such:

```
Branch: {
    title: 'Branch',
    type: 'list',
    options: {
        '1': 'Auckland',
        '2': 'Queensland'
    }
}
```

I want to be able to use a mysql query (JSON'ed?) for my "options" instead of hardcoding it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do is on the php side I query everything and put it into an array and then echo it to the javascript page:

```
            Branch: {
                title: 'Branch',
                type: 'list',
                options: <?php echo json_encode($branchArray)?>
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Branch:{
  title: 'Page Name',
  width: '30%',
  options:  'FieldNameLoader.php?action=Branch',
  list :true
}

if($_GET["action"] == "Branch") {


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from tblPagelist ORDER BY PageName ASC;");
$rows = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $eil = array();
    $eil["DisplayText"] = $row[1];
    $eil["Value"] = $row[0];
    $rows[] = $eil;
    }
$jTableResult = array();
$jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
$jTableResult['Options'] = $rows;  
print json_encode($jTableResult);    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP's json_encode with mysql_fetch_array

PHP

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  $options[$row['id']] = $row['name'];
}

$options = json_encode($options);
```

JSON

```
Branch: {
  title: 'Branch',
  type: 'list',
  options: <?=$options?>
}
```

Comment: doing this doesnt load the page at all.. I even tried putting <?php=$options?> but still nothing.. I checked the PHP and echo'ed the json, it is showing properly, but somehow the jquery plugin is refusing to load. Using options: <?php echo json_encode($options) ?> inside the jquery, the page loads, but the plugin is not showing the options displayed by the json

Comment: OK, I was able to finally get it to work using `<?php echo json_encode($options) ?>` Just forgot to remove the comment of my include.. lol